# How to get the length of the text inside the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React component, where I have some dynamic text:

```
...
let spanLength

return(
  <SomeComp>
     ...
     <span>Some static text: {someDynamicText}, {someAnotherText}</span>
     ...
  </SomeComp>
)
```

How can I get the length of text inside `span` element to a `spanLength` variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `ref` to your `span`

```
let spanRef = React.createRef()
...
<span ref={spanRef}>Some static text: {someDynamicText}, {someAnotherText}</span>
```

Then the text length would simply be `spanRef.current.textContent.length`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: upd: Sounds good, but I got `Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`

Comment: `React.createRef` is asynchronous, so you won't immediately get the value in the `App` component, you can get it later, eg on function click but you won't be able to update the DOM. You will need to use a class based component with a `render()` method, so you can update the DOM as well. Check: https://codesandbox.io/s/rtqxm

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Any way this can be done in a function component using the new hook useRef?

Comment: @AtinSingh I'm afraid I do not have much knowledge about the new hooks.

Answer (score 8):

Why not, first, compose the whole string? You can grab its length immediately after, and then render it.

```
const spanStr = `Some static text: ${someDynamicText}, ${someAnotherText}`;
const spanLength = spanStr.length;

return(
  <SomeComp>
     ...
     <span>{spanStr}</span>
     ...
  </SomeComp>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, but I can't just move all my text content to a variable, because I have some another components, which is subscribed to context inside span.

Comment: So when the content of the span changes the content of other components changes too? You might be better off lifting that state up to a parent component if possible and sharing the same text between them.